# C# htmlagilitypack XPATH return System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xpath

My code as following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
   {
     class Program
       {
        static void Main(string[] args)
          {

             HtmlWeb webClient = new HtmlWeb();

             HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = webClient.Load("https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=0001.HK");

             string date = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"/html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").InnerText;

            Console.Write(date);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
     }
}
```

But the Xpath return null value, I used XPATH helper to check, it is correct (please see attached picture)

[XPATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd0Yn.jpg)

Can anyone give me some idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which node you actually want to extract, by your XPath I understand you want the first column in the table, am I correct?
There are many reasons why your XPath returned null, the primary one is that you should use more generic XPath. The addon you use is good, but it shows you a very very specific XPath, so if the smallest thing changes in the page, even a thing you can not see, the XPath is no longer valid. Another note to remember is that your browser changes the HTML (for instance, I faced so many differences made by Chrome, especially with tables which become 'Div' by Chrome). Another important note, when using id/class names to extract XPath, I prefer using 'contains' instead of the actual name because, as mentioned above, they both can change as well.

**TL;DR:**

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[contains(@class, 'yfnc')]//table//td[contains(@class, 'yfnc_tabledata1')][1]");
if(node != null)
{
  // Extract its InnerText
}
```

One last thing, when you extract a node, you should check if it's null first before trying to extract its InnerText, or wrap it with a 'try' - 'catch' clause, to catch the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Sorry, I tried your code. It still return null

Hope some body can add more comments